# Why is scikit-learn not installing on python 3.8 using pycharm on windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pip

When I try to install scikit-learn using PyCharm by going into the settings->Project Settings->Project Interpreter-> '+' button and serching for and installing scikit-learn, it gives me this error:

Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '"C:'

I installed numpy without any problems before this.

Is there anything I am missing or another way I can try to install scikit-learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I found the answer.
For anyone out there with the same problem as me, you should go to settings->Project Settings->Project Interpreter in Pycharm. There you will find pip, which for me was out dated. If this is the case, then click on pip and then the upgrade button that looks like an up arrow. After it finishes installing the latest version of pip, retry installing scikit-learn or any other package that would not previously install and gave the error "Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '"C:'"